# WPF Binding to a child collection

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I have the following entities:

```
public class User
{
    public User()
    {
        Roles = new ObservableCollection<Role>();
    }

    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Role> Roles { get; set; }
}

public class Role
{
    public int RoleId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

With this ViewModel:

```
public class UserManagerViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    public ObservableCollection<Role> AllRoles { get; set; }
    public UserViewModel()
    {
        AllRoles = new ObservableCollection<Role>(RoleRepository.GetAll());
    }

    private User _selectedUser;
    public User SelectedUser
    {
        get { return _selectedUser; }
        set
        {
            if (_selectedUser != value)
            {
                _selectedUser = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

I want to display the `SelectedUser` roles in the following way(or anything similar):

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <vm:UserManagerViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding AllRoles}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <CheckBox Content="{Binding Name}" IsChecked="{Binding ???}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
 </ListBox>
```

To what do I need to set the `IsChecked` property of the `CheckBox` so that it will represent the `SelectedUser` roles?

Comment: UserManagerViewModel is missing in sample.

Comment: @Maximus My bad, UserViewModel == UserManagerViewModel

Comment: With WPF, your data is your application, not the UI. UI is just a pretty user-friendly reflection of your data. If you need to know if something is selected or not, you should have that property on your data model. In your case, I would add an IsSelected property to your Role object, and when the SelectedUser changes, I'd go through AllRolles and update the IsSelected property to match the selected user. Of course, assuming users can modify and save roles, you'll want some way to propagate their changes back to the `SelectedUser` too

Comment: @Rachel I agree with the approach you suggested and currently working on implementing it. Since `User` and `Role` are entities generated by `Entity-Framework` I prefer to create a `RoleViewModel` that will hold the role name and an `IsChecked` property.

Comment: @Yoav Yep, I'd agree with that decision :) I was going to include that but then it wouldn't fit into a comment and I'd have to take the time to write a property answer. I think I may actually have had a class at one point that would simply add an IsSelected or IsChecked value to an existing object since this kind of thing was rather common for me... I can't remember now though. I want to say it was used like `ObservableCollection<SelectableObject<Role>>`, but I don't recall.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you want to "check" roles that `SelectedUser` has.

First we answer the question, "What data does this depend on?" The answer is pretty simple, it depends on the role itself, so we write:

```
<CheckBox Content="{Binding Name}" IsChecked="{Binding .}"/>
```

Now clearly, that isn't a bool; so we will need to write a converter for it that checks against a collection. We *could* do a MultiValueConverter here (as in @Moji's answer), but it's probably easier to expose the collection via a Dependency Property, and bind when creating the converter.

```
<Window.Resources>
   <local:CollectionContainsConverter Collection="{Binding SelectedUser.Roles}"/>
</Window.Resources>

<CheckBox Content="{Binding Name}" IsChecked="{Binding Path=., Converter={StaticResource CollectionContainsConverter}"/>
```

And the converter:

```
public class CollectionContainsConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public IEnumerable<object> Collection { get; set; } //This is actually a DP

    public object Convert(...)
    {
        return Collection.Contains(value);
        // or possibly, to allow for the Object.Equals override
        return Collection.Any(o => o.Equals(value));
    }

    public object ConvertBack(...)
    {
         return Binding.DoNothing;
    }
}
```

Having not tested this, you may need to use the second return so it doesn't compare references, and utilize `Object.Equals` (or another comparator of your choice) to figure out if the item is in the list.

Answer (score 0):

you can use MultipleBinding and MultipleValueVonverter as below

```
  <Grid>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <local:RoleValueConverter x:Key="converter"></local:RoleValueConverter>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding AllRoles}" >
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <CheckBox Content="{Binding Name}" >
                        <CheckBox.IsChecked>
                            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource converter}">
                                <Binding Path="."></Binding>
                                <Binding  RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListBox}}"  Path="DataContext"></Binding>
                            </MultiBinding>
                        </CheckBox.IsChecked>
                    </CheckBox>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
 public class RoleValueConverter : IMultiValueConverter
    {

        public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
           //values[0] is Role object
    //value[1] is UserManagerViewModel 
   // then you can see if Selected user had Role object return true else return false 
        }

        public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```